# Tracking where error was generated using stacktrace from Bugsense report in Windows Phone app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, bugsense

I have had an app on the windows phone store for awhile now and a few people have been emailing me about bugs. I could not replicate the issues so I added bugsense to my app. Now I am starting to get error reports which is great.

One of the reports I recieved today had the following in the stacktrace

```
at Microsoft.Phone.Reactive.ObservableExtensions.b__3[TSource](Exception exception)
at Microsoft.Phone.Reactive.AnonymousObserver`1.Error(Exception exception)
at Microsoft.Phone.Reactive.AbstractObserver`1.OnError(Exception exception)
at Microsoft.Phone.Reactive.AnonymousObservable`1.AutoDetachObserver.Error(Exception exception)
at Microsoft.Phone.Reactive.AbstractObserver`1.OnError(Exception exception)
at Microsoft.Phone.Reactive.Observable.<>c__DisplayClass161`1.<>c__DisplayClass163.b__160()
at Microsoft.Phone.Reactive.CurrentThreadScheduler.Trampoline.Run()
at Microsoft.Phone.Reactive.CurrentThreadScheduler.EnsureTrampoline(Action action)
at Microsoft.Phone.Reactive.AnonymousObservable`1.Subscribe(IObserver`1 observer)
at Microsoft.Phone.Reactive.Observable.<>c__DisplayClass323`1.<>c__DisplayClass325.b__31e()
at Microsoft.Phone.Reactive.ThreadPoolScheduler.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__3(Object _)
at System.Threading.Timer.ring()
```

Comment was The operation has timed-out.

The problems is I use Observable in various places through out the app so how can I track where the error is being generated?

EDIT:
I have just spotted the Observable.TimeOut that I am using, could this be the cause?

```
IObservable<IEvent<TheWeatherBug.GetLocationListCompletedEventArgs>> observable =
            Observable.FromEvent<TheWeatherBug.GetLocationListCompletedEventArgs>(WeatherBugService, "GetLocationListCompleted").Take(1);

            var ObservableTimeout = Observable.Timeout(observable, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

            ObservableTimeout.Subscribe(w =>
            {
                pbarSearch.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;

                if (w.EventArgs.Error == null)
                {
                    locations = w.EventArgs.Result;

                    foreach (TheWeatherBug.ApiLocationData ap in locations)
                    {
                        if (ap.City.Contains(location))
                            if (!lbxLocations.Items.Contains(ap.City + " - " + ap.Country))
                                lbxLocations.Items.Add(ap.City + " - " + ap.Country);
                    }

                    if (lbxLocations.Items.Count == 0)
                        MessageBox.Show("Sorry could not find a city called " + location);
                }
            });
```